# How to add Parameter inside a LIKE statement using Data Environment

Tags: sql, vb6

I'm trying to pass a parameter from my form to Data Environment which I done, although when using Like statement I'm having problems, ? is my parameter

Here is my sql statement in Data Environment

```
 SELECT space(t . LEVEL * 6) + c.description AS Name, c.customercode, c.remarks FROM customer c INNER JOIN memberstree t ON c.customercode = t .customercode WHERE  pedigree LIKE '/?%' ORDER BY t .pedigree + ltrim(str(t .node, 6, 0))
```

Here is how I pass it from a form

```
    Load DataEnvironment1
    With DataEnvironment1
    Set DataGrid1.DataSource = .rsMembersTree
    If .rsMembersTree.State <> 0 Then .rsMembersTree.Close
    .MembersTree (mRootNode)
    End With
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolve my problem the correct syntax would be '/' + ? + '%'  and should change data type from integer to string.